# OpenLayers changing vector layers based on user input

Tags: openlayers, gis

I'm new to OpenLayers and would like to know if one can set up a map, say zip code boundaries for a specific county, and then turn vector layers of and on based on user input. Input would be in the form of radio buttons and the data I want to display is public health related information by zip code.

For example if the user wants to view pregnancies to mothers under the age of 18, I'd like a thematic map displaying that data by zip code. Or, for example, income, the same kind of output.

So, there would be radio buttons representing the desired data to be displayed and then the user would select which information they'd like to see.

I know how to get the data (metro health department) and geographical boundaries (census). I just want to know if this is possible. The documentation for OpenLayers is driving me mad and I do not want to waste months just trying stuff and hoping that it will work out. I know that I'll have to get a working knowledge of JavaScript but that does not intimidate me.

Thanks!
-Briggs

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using OpenLayers as you can use JavaScript to turn on/off the vector layers. See h[ide/show display of layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.display).
You may also use one layer and simply replace/reload it on user input change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OpenLayers provides a LayerSwitcher control to do just this, as long as you have some sort of data server to provide the layers.  And as long as you don't mind the default OpenLayers look-and-feel, the Javascript is straightforward.  "View Source" for the sample at http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/controls.html, and replace the example layers with your own.